# Randomly assign the value of a variable within a group

Tags: r, random

I would like to randomly assign (in R) for each id_individual within an id_group the value 0 or 1. Each group is composed of two individuals and the random_var should respect the following condition (within a group) : sum(random_var)==1.

More precisely, I would like my random var be like :

| ID_GROUP | ID_INDIVIDUAL | Random_var |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

Any idea how to code this request in R?

Thanks!

Chloé

Answer (score 3):

You can try `sample` within `ave`

```
> transform(df, Random_var = +(ave(ID_INDIVIDUAL, ID_GROUP, FUN = sample) == 1))
  ID_GROUP ID_INDIVIDUAL Random_var
1        1             1          0
2        1             2          1
3        2             1          1
4        2             2          0
```

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` option using `group_by` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID_GROUP) %>%
  mutate(Random_var = sample(0:1))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   ID_GROUP [2]
#>   ID_GROUP ID_INDIVIDUAL Random_var
#>      <int>         <int>      <int>
#> 1        1             1          0
#> 2        1             2          1
#> 3        2             1          1
#> 4        2             2          0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks but It doesn't the respect the condition of having the sum of random_var equal to 1 within each group. For each group, I would like a line with 1 and a line with 0

Comment: Hi @Chloe_pa, Assuming each group has only 2 observations, then using `sample(0:1)` will always return a 0 and 1 which is in total 1, right?

Comment: Yes. I've oversimplified the structure of my data that's why it doesn't work. In fact, I have some groups with 1 observation, and for these groups I would like to randomly assign 0 or 1, and some groups with 2 observations, and for these one I would like to randomly assign a line to 1 and the other to 0.

Comment: @Chloe_pa Just replace `sample(0:1)` with `sample(0:1, n())` in the `mutate()`. That may work for the situation you described above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with a custom function:

```
my_binary <- function(n) {
  vec <- rep(0, n)
  if(n == 1) {
    vec <- sample(c(0, 1), 1)
  } else {
    vec[sample(n, 1)] <- 1
  }
  return(vec)
}



library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID_GROUP) %>%
  mutate(Random_var = my_binary(n()))

ID_GROUP ID_INDIVIDUAL Random_var
     <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>
1        1             1          0
2        1             2          1
3        2             1          0
4        2             2          1
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID_GROUP = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  ID_INDIVIDUAL = c(1, 2, 1, 2)
)
```

Comment: For group with only one observation, this function returns always 1

Comment: You are right. I will update!